# How parametrized varags functions know to create an arrays of a specific type

Tags: java, generics

I am reading through Angelika Langer's JavaGenericsFAQ and I have a problem with understanding type erasure with varags function. In the FAQ the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = method_1("bad", "karma"); // ClassCastException
}

static <T> T[] method_1(T t1, T t2) {
    return method_2(t1, t2);
}

static <T> T[] method_2(T... args) {
    return args;
}
```

could be roughly translated to the following after the type erasure:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = (String[]) method_1("bad", "karma");// ClassCastException
}

static Object[] method_1(Object t1, Object t2) {
    return method_2(new Object[]{t1, t2});
}

static Object[] method_2(Object[] args) {
    return args;
}
```

This answers the question from FAQ why calling *method_1* is a bad idea (method one passes *T* type parameter which is non-reifiable and due to the type erasure the compiler does not create a *T[]*, but an *Object[]*) but that got me thinking: how Java is able to handle the following call:

```
String[] strings = method_2("good", "karma");
```

How does *method_2* know to actually create a String[] array since type erasure took place?

Comment: In other words, it translates to `String[] strings = (String[])method_2(new String[] {"good", "karma"});`

Comment: @user15793316 right, now I get it. I checked the bytecode for the _main_ method and found out that it creates an String array (`anewarray class java/lang/String`) and after that it calls the _method_2_ (`invokestatic  method_2:([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;`) which in fact does not know anything about T parameter